# Radio button solid fill not printing in Material Design Lite

Tags: material-design-lite

The solid fill on the MDL radio button will not print.  I turned on the show background graphics on the printer settings, with no luck.  Does this work for anybody else?

[image]

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @nqngo - Just print the sample page on the Material Design Lite website: https://getmdl.io/components/#toggles-section/radio  It may only print the checkbox page, but it shows how they don't print either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the inner circle is a background color, not displayed by default in most browsers when printing the page.

I fixed that quick&dirty with :

`@media print { .mdl-radio__inner-circle { border: 4px solid #000; } }`